# How can I help users to avoid runaway processes when using pipes in a script?

Tags: linux, bash

Here's a sample bash script to show updates to a file.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
inotifywait -m file1.txt | while read -r line; do
    echo line
done
```

If I save this script as `showme.h` and then execute it at a prompt, I end up with 3 processes:

```
username 14652  9811  0 16:53 pts/2    00:00:00 bash ./showme.sh
username 14653 14652  0 16:53 pts/2    00:00:00 inotifywait -m file1.txt
username 14654 14652  0 16:53 pts/2    00:00:00 bash ./showme.sh
```

If I end the initial process via ctrl-c, all 3 processes die. However, if I kill an individual process, only that process dies, unless I kill the whole process group via -pid.

Since I intend to distribute this script for others to use, I want to make it simple for others to manage. Having 3 different processes floating around is cumbersome. For that matter, a user might discover `showme.sh` processes running via `pgrep`, but never discover that `inotifywait` is still out there, and so fail to kill it. Granted, a user who kills the process group directly should not have this problem, but users don't always do things correctly.

My question: is there a better way that I can make ending this process more foolproof, so as to reduce the likelihood that uninformed users end up with runaway processes? A solution that would allow me to restructure my above script so that only one process results would be perfect, but I suspect that's not generally possible. I there's an entirely different way I should be thinking about this, I'd love to hear that too.

(Yes, I know that in the inotifywait case in particular, I could do so by not running it as a monitor and restarting it every time in the loop, but that might miss some updates. Regardless, I'd like to know what the more general answer is if there is one.)

Comment: "runaway processes" ? Have you witnessed these in this context? (I'm surprized). Maybe add a `trap` with a function that does a cleanup? Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's worth looking at the process tree:

1. bash (top level script)
2. inotifywait (pipeline, part 1)
3. bash (pipeline, part 2, read/echo loop)

Termination rules:

- Task #1 will terminate when task #3 terminates (which depends on task #2)
- Task #2 will terminate when task #3 terminates, and when it has something to write
  (it will get EPIPE)
- Task #3 will terminate when task #2 terminates,
  which will close the input pipe with EOF

Proposed solution is to trap the 'EXIT' condition in the 2 bash instances, and kill the inotifywait process, which will allow the whole pipeline to exit gracefully.

```
function cleanup {
        [ -s "$PID_FILE" ] && kill $(<$PID_FILE)
        rm -f $PID_FILE
}

PID_FILE=pid.file
echo > $PID_FILE
trap 'cleanup' EXIT
( echo $BASHPID > $PID_FILE  && exec inotifywait -m file1.txt) |
        { trap 'cleanup' EXIT ; while read x ; do echo "$x" ; done }
rm -f $PID_FILE
```

Another alternative is to setup specific trap on all possible user signals. However, from the OP input, users are not careful to follow rules, so it is hard to define signal handlers for all possible combinations.

Answer (score 1):

**[Frame challenge:](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6842/whats-a-frame-challenge/6843#6843)** I wouldn't worry about any of this. You'll contort yourself into a pretzel trying to make your script idiot proof. Linux users are expected to be responsible for their actions. If they choose to kill a process the fallout and cleanup are on them.

It's a fact of life that in Linux child processes don't automatically die when their parent does. It is common for children to outlive their parents. Parent processes are not, in general, expected to cleanup their children; nor are children expected to kill themselves if their parent dies.

(Usually programs will naturally end anyways. In the pipeline above `inotifywait` will receive a SIGPIPE signal when it tries to write to the broken pipe, and the `while` loop will be signalled when it tries to read from it. This will cause both processes to naturally terminate if the other dies.)

Comment: Thanks for the frame challenge, and it's food for thought I'll consider. I appreciate it.

Comment: Regarding the specific point on inotifywait dying anyway; when I run my sample script, it creates *two* bash processes, and then an inotifywait process. What you say regarding processes dying anyway works for me if I kill the second bash process, but not the first.

Comment: That's right. As @dash-o explained in their answer, tasks 2 (inotifywait) and 3 (the read/echo loop) will die when the other one does, but neither watches for the death of task 1 (the top level script).